# Error code 403 while web scrapping Zoopla website

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I was trying to scrape a zoopla.co.uk website for a postcode, but I kept on getting the HTTP Error 403 (does it think I'm a bot)?

Here is my code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup



head = {
  "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"
}

url  = "https://www.zoopla.co.uk/to-rent/property/west-midlands/handsworth/sandwell-road/b21-8nl/?q=B21%208NL&radius=1"

data = requests.get(url, head)
data.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

This site is protected by cloudflare, as you said, yes, It blocks your request. Maybe by selenium and some methods you can reach your goral, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled") 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) 
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False) 
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Dont't forget using time.sleep() if you send many requests, it helps you not detected as robot.